# Making a (Circular) Phylogenetic Tree in Python

Tags: python, xml, data-visualization, visualization, biopython

I'm trying to make a cool graphic for my ecology class - one that shows how different classes of microbes are related to each other.

I have this `xml` file that encodes a phylogenetic tree.

```
<phyloxml xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.phyloxml.org" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.phyloxml.org http://www.phyloxml.org/1.10/phyloxml.xsd">
  <phylogeny rooted="false">
    <clade>
      <clade>
        <name>Methanopyri</name>
      </clade>
      <clade>
        <clade>
          <name>Methanococci</name>
        </clade>
        <clade>
          <clade>
            <clade>
              <name>Thermococci</name>
            </clade>
            <clade>
              <name>Thermoplasmata</name>
            </clade>
          </clade>
          <clade>
            <clade>
              <name>Methanobacteria</name>
            </clade>
            <clade>
              <clade>
                <name>Archaeoglobi</name>
              </clade>
              <clade>
                <clade>
                  <name>Methanomicrobia</name>
                </clade>
                <clade>
                  <name>Haloarchaea</name>
                </clade>
              </clade>
            </clade>
          </clade>
        </clade>
      </clade>
    </clade>
  </phylogeny>
</phyloxml>
```

Using the `Bio` library I'm able to make a graphic that looks kinda boring.

```
from Bio import Phylo

def build_tree(fname: str):
    """ build a tree from a file """
    tree = Phylo.read(fname, 'phyloxml')
    return tree

if __name__ == '__main__':
    tree = build_tree('microbes.xml')
```

I get the following image:

[image: Phylogenetic tree one - linear and boring.]

I'd much rather have something like this:

[image: Phylogenetic tree two - circular and cool.]

How could I go about doing this? I'm having a hard time finding good libraries.

Comment: Is the purpose of the plot to impress people or to present information? If it's the latter then the "boring" plot will work much better.

Comment: Kinda both, but more on the side of impressing people. There's not a whole lot of nodes so I don't think the round tree would be sensory overload.

Comment: It's not only about sensory overload, more important is the well-known fact that text tilted by more than 45 degrees is unreadable so you have to tilt your head to read it. 
But if you're still keen: http://etetoolkit.org/   

https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/auto_examples/drawing/plot_circular_tree.html   

https://plotly.com/python/tree-plots/

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution.

```
from Bio import Phylo
from ete3 import Tree, TreeStyle

def build_tree(fname: str):
    """ build a tree from a file """
    tree = Phylo.read(fname, 'phyloxml')
    return tree

if __name__ == '__main__':
    tree = build_tree('microbes.xml')

# Phylo.draw(tree) # this shows the image you already have

def build_tree_for_ete3(clade):
    # convert a biopython tree to an ete3 tree
    builded_tree = Tree()
    for child in clade.clades:
        child_tree = build_tree_for_ete3(child)
        builded_tree.add_child(child=child_tree, name=child.name, dist=child.branch_length)
    return builded_tree

builded_tree = build_tree_for_ete3(tree.root)

ts = TreeStyle()
ts.show_leaf_name = True
ts.mode = "c"
ts.arc_start = -90 # 0 degrees = 3 o'clock
ts.arc_span = 360
ts.show_leaf_name = True
builded_tree.show(tree_style=ts)
```

It gives something like this :

[Circular representation of a phylogenetic tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pRrrA.png)

You will have to install the ete3 library (http://etetoolkit.org/) with something like :

```
pip install ete3
pip install PyQt5
```